# Google Drive Windows App to/from fileId - items with same names, and multiple parents

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm trying to translate from a Google Drive link on the web (well, the fileId anyway) to the Windows Google Drive app's path on the hard disk, and back again.

It would be helpful if there was something in the API for this (eg produce a path excluding the `C:\Users\[User]\Google Drive\` from a file/folder ID, and vice versa), but there isn't.

So far I do:

1. Windows Path to ID: get the first folder of the path and (starting from the root) look for a matching folder, then repeat until finished (possibly with a file name). PROBLEM: Items can be called the same thing, whether files or folders or combinations of both, which is tricky in Windows. The app adds a number ' (1)' and so on, which I have to catch, but how can I know which item ID is the correct one? I believe that numbering is based on date but I'm not sure. So I can potentially end up with multiple results and no way to tell which is which.
2. ID to Windows Path: take the name of the file/folder from the ID, then keep adding the parent folder(s) until I build up a path. PROBLEM: same as 1 above, if there are multiple matching items then I can't tell which I should use when translating to Windows. PROBLEM: Apparently items in Google Drive can have more than one parent. Not sure how that works in the Windows app.

Can anyone help me fine tune how I do this, or tell me the exact details of how the Google Drive app does it? Code is welcome but not required, and I in turn can provide the code I use if needed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I fully understand the question, but I try to smack an answer anyway:

1/ assuming you have a Windows path,

> C:\Users\User\Google Drive\myfile.ext

you create a file with a similar path on GooDrive iterating your path's tokens
  recursively creating a tree structure on GooDrive. If the tree nodes (folders/files) exist, return ID's, otherwise create the objects. The main difference in GooDrive is that title query may return multiple objects (list of folders/files). Bad luck, you either use the first one or quit with an error.

```
  global path = "C:\Users\User\Google Drive\myfile.ext"
  createTree(String path) {
    rootFolderId = create your root or use GooDrive root
    fileId = iterate (firstToken(path, "\"), rootFolderId);
  } 

  iterate(title, parentFolderId) {
    ID (or multiple IDs) = search for title in parentFolderId

    if (multiple IDs exist) 
      BOOM - report error and quit or use the first one

    if (token not last) {
      if (single ID for title exists) {
        folderId = found ID
      } else {  
        folderId = createFolder with title and parentFolderId metadata
      }
      iterate(nextToken(path, "\"), folderId)

    } else {   (last token represent file)
      if (single ID for title exists) {
        fileId = found ID
      } else {  
        fileId = createFile with title and parentFolderId metadata
      }
      return fileId    
    }
  }
```

You did not specify the language, but in case it is Java, you can see similar procedure [here](https://github.com/seanpjanson/RESTDemo/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/spjanson/restdemo/MainActivity.java) in the *createTree()* method (it is Android code, so there is a lot of Android specific goo there, sorry)

2/ assuming you have a Google Drive ***fileId***, you construct the Windows path with this pseudocode (going from bottom up to the root). Again, you may have multiple parents you have to deal with (error or multiple paths with links to a single object)

```
  String path = fileId's title

  while () {
    parentID  = get fileId's parent

    if (multiple parentIDs exist) 
      BOOM - report error and quit or construct multiple paths
      (multiple paths would represent file/folder links)

    if (parentID not valid or parentId's title not valid)
      break

    path = parentID's title + "\" + path

     if (parentID's title is your root)
      break
  }
```

One more thing: You say "Folders and files can be called the same thing..."
In GooDrive, look at the MIME type, there is a specific MIME type "application/vnd.google-apps.folder" that tells you it is a folder. Also, any parentId metadata represents folder, since files can't be parents.

Good Luck

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me, I appreciate it. The C# code I have basically does exactly that. But I am specifically trying to work with the Windows Google Drive app, and match their systems for naming files etc. So I am trying to improve on your/my system by adding or recognising (depending on which way we are going) the numbering they add when there are multiple children with the same name. Otherwise there's a pretty good chance this system will fail at some point, maybe many.

Comment: As for what happens if there are multiple parents, I'm curious what the Windows app does but frankly it's less of a concern as I don't think it will ever come up on files created in the Windows app.

Comment: I don't work on Windows anymore (Android only - hobby), so I don't have any knowledge / opinion on the matter. In my universe, I mainly fight the problem  'file/folder does not exist -> create a new one'. Considering unreliable/latent network (cellular), this is the nightmare scenario where I end up with multiple objects with same name on GooDrive. But I digress.

Comment: I've edited for clarity on the files/folders sharing the same name. Any items can share the same names, whether it's two or more files, or two or more folders, or two or more files and folders.

Comment: It all comes from the fact that it is a FLAT system with the only UNIQUE item being the ID (ResourceId), The title (name) is just another metadata.  It has never designed to be hierarchic (tree).

Comment: Yes indeed.... but Google Drive for Windows _does_ translate it to a hierarchic tree where names cannot be duplicated within a folder, and where items cannot have more than one parent - so there must be a system to that, and that's what I'm hoping to find out.

Comment: It is easy to handle it in the WIN -> GOODrive direction since traditional OSs  (DOS, WIN, UNIX, ...) have enforced tree structure (which is a subset of GOODrive's system), The other way around, you have problems that you have to decide. For instance which PARENT (in multiparent situation) holds a CHILD object and which ones will hold secondary links. Or you may decide to make multiple physical copies, but how will you handle updates? You have to make that architectural decision or go and analyze how Google's app does it.  Should be easy with web Drive on one side and Win Drive on another.

Comment: On http://drive.google.com, copy a file to 2 locations on and watch Win app. Modify the two,  Or create 2 files with the same name ... I myself in an app that needs strict tree structure just report an error when II hit the multiple titles(names) or multiple parents

Comment: Re: creating 2 files and watching what happens, that's how I came to the conclusion it's probably date related.... but it's hard to be sure. Are there other factors? Frankly, I'm hoping someone from Google will comment. Re: easier for WIN -> GD, not so... if you have two files called 'A.txt' and 'A (1).txt' you have to catch that case, rule out that the 'A (1).txt' matches a GD file called 'A (1).txt', and then figure out which of the two GD files called 'A.txt' is being referred to. And what if there's GD files A.txt, A.txt and A (1).txt and A (2).txt - does the second A.txt become A (3).txt?