# How to upload a folder to Google drive programmatically

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

I want to upload a folder to Google drive in my android app programmatically. Is there an api which would let me upload / copy an entire folder in my android device to Google drive while preserving the directory structure?

All documentation and examples only talk about file uploads but not folder.

Comment: what you have done so far ?

Comment: I have found only examples of uploading files to Google drive using java rest api called insert. And some posts talk about astro manager app which does this. But is there not native programmatic support for uploading entire folder keeping the structure.

Answer (score 4):

You have 2 different ways to do it. Specifically, 2 different APIs, the [REST Api](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/about-sdk) and the [GDAA](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/intro).

Basically, the algorithm goes like this:

1/ find root folder
2/ use it as a parent of your first level folder and create one (if not exist)
3/ wash, rinse, repeat until you reach your file level
4/ create a file with parent reference

You implement it recursively if you don't know your directory structure depth, otherwise you can use a 'spaghetti' approach ('for' loop).

You can see an implementation of this problem in the '*createTree()*' method in this demo for the [REST Api](https://github.com/seanpjanson/RESTDemo/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/spjanson/restdemo/MainActivity.java), or you can implement it under [GDAA](https://github.com/seanpjanson/GDAADemo/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/spjanson/gdaademo/MainActivity.java).

You can also look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33730395/google-drive-windows-app-to-from-fileid-items-with-same-names-and-multiple-pa/33733987#33733987), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34084850/google-drive-api-get-list-of-files-including-folders/34088930#34088930) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34053840/drive-api-save-to-folder-if-folder-doesnt-exist-create-than-save/34056895#34056895) SO answer to get better understanding of the problem

Good Luck

Comment: Thanks Sean. I was wondering if an api existed which would do this in the drive API. If i need to anyways implement this its pretty straight forward. I will implement this. THanks a lot for the reply